# How can I use `ddev auth ssh` with a YubiKey?

Tags: docker, ssh, ddev, yubikey

I use a [YubiKey](https://www.yubico.com/) for my SSH and because of this my `/home/<redacted>/.ssh/` folder has no keys:

```
/home/<redacted>/.ssh/
├── config
├── id_rsa_yubikey.pub
└── known_hosts
```

And because I have no keys in my `/home/<redacted>/.ssh/` folder I get the following error when running `ddev auth ssh`:

```
Docker command 'docker [run -it --rm --volumes-from=ddev-ssh-agent --user=1001 --entrypoint= --mount=type=bind,src=/home/<redacted>/.ssh,dst=/tmp/sshtmp drud/ddev-ssh-agent:v1.20.0-built bash -c cp -r /tmp/sshtmp ~/.ssh && chmod -R go-rwx ~/.ssh && cd ~/.ssh && ssh-add $(file * | awk -F: "/private key/ { print \$1 }")]' failed: exit status 1
```

Is there a way to get `ddev auth ssh` working with a YubiKey?

Answer (score 3):

After a push in the right direction and some trial and error I got it working.

The solution for me was to add a `docker-compose.ssh.yaml` file in the `.ddev` folder:

```
services:
  web:
    environment:
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
    volumes:
      - ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}:/ssh-agent
```

Comment: Glad it worked! Related: https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/1904 - I'm not actually sure anything but traditional Windows needs the older technique now, we should use this one most places